# Android Source tree switching branch

Tags: android, branch, repo

I have downloaded whole working tree with the following command:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync
```

Now I wanted to switch to a branch android-6.0.1_r3.

So I did,

```
repo init -b android-6.0.1_r3
repo sync.
```

It is again downloading a bunch of stuff. Is it really supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it works right.
Android source code use repo to manage the whole git res. if you want to switch android branch, in fact, you really need repo init another branch and sync . but wether it is download new code or just checkout ever git res , I can't tell .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to a branch, just do this:

```
git checkout android-6.0.1_r3
```

Comment: I don't understand this. Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: I have tried "git checkout android-6.0.1_r3", it also seems normal.